# how to call xib file from storyboard on button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

I am new in swift I want to call .xib file from storyboard on button click.
I am using code like this but it crash because .xib file is not in storyboard

```
 let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "abcViewController") as! abcViewController
 self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

this code

```
 let newViewController = abcViewController(nibName: "abcViewController", bundle: nil)
 self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

screen like this
[image]

I just change line and now its work fine

```
 let newViewController = abcViewController(nibName: "abcViewController", bundle: nil)
 //self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You have a xib inside storyboard ?

Comment: @Sailendra No it is not inside.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong,  you have a button in storyboard and you want to load a xib on button click right?

Comment: @Sailendra its done thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let newViewController = abcViewController(nibName: "xibFileName", bundle: nil)
//If you want to present xib
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

//If you want to push xib in navigation stack
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I edited question it is not showing screens properly.

Comment: Add comments, explain your answer, read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

@Mujtaba to fix the screen issue not showing full screen go to you view controller in the storyboard and change the presentation style to full screeen [image]

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:

```
// Register Xib
let abcViewController = ABCViewController(nibName: "abcViewController", bundle: nil)
// Present VC "Modally" style
self.present(abcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

set the ID as `abcViewController` as same class name

Thanks